# Statistics-relationships between gamma and exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Just want to clarify whether the following is correct:
If gamma(a,b) ,then exp(a/b)?

where a,b are parameters for gamma 
and a/b is the parameter for exp

for example, gamma(1,2)=exp(1/2)
Is this true for every a,b>0?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PDF for the $\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)$ distribution is
$$ f(x)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}e^{-\lambda x}$$
for $x>0$. This is not the PDF for any exponential distribution unless $\alpha=1$.

However, the gamma and exponential distributions are closely related: if $X_1,\dots,X_k$ are independent and exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, then $X_1+\dots+X_k$ is $\Gamma$ distributed with parameters $k$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: means if alpha=1, then gamma(1,b)=exp(1/b)?

Comment: If $\alpha=1$, then the gamma distribution is in fact an exponential distribution.

Comment: What if K isn’t an integer?

Comment: @Stanislas Hildebrandt: the gamma distribution is defined for non-integer $\alpha$, but it doesn't really make sense to sum up a non-integer number of exponential random variables.